# Using External JS File in Pkg Node JS

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm working on a program that will take some user inputs in a config file and then run a script with that file.

I used pkg to compile it so that my source code can be hidden and only allow users to change the config files and used a js file for the configs and then imported them to the main file using module.exports.

MAIN FILE

```
let {var1,var2,var3,var4} = require('./config.js');
let {var1,var2} = require('./config2.js');
```

CONFIG FILE

```
module.exports = {var1:var1, var2:var2, var3:var3, var4:var4}
```

When I run the compiled program it seems like it's using the original files I had in the source folder rather than importing from the files I have in the same folder as the program.

Is there any work around to have it load the files the user will have on their device rather than the ones I had when I compiled?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?